# Pass values from array to object? - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop

My problem, simplified is:

```
class A {
  public $a;
  public $b;

  function f1 () {
     // Code
  }
}

$obj = new A();

$arr = array ("a" => 1, "b" => 2);
```

How can I put the contents of $arr into $obj? (Obviously without $obj->a = $arr["a"], suppose there are thousands of values)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A foreach loop and a variable variable:

```
foreach ($arr as $name => $value) {
  $obj->$name = $value;
}
```

You probably shouldn't have thousands of variables in your class though.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `get_class_vars()` function like -

```
<?php
class A {
  public $a;
  public $b;

  function f1 () {
     // Code
  }
}    

$obj = new A();   

$arr = array ("a" => 1, "b" => 2);

$vars = get_class_vars("A");

foreach($vars as $var=>$value)
    $obj->$var = $arr[$var];

print_r($obj);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A same as (discarding protected & private member):

```
foreach ($obj as $property_name => $property_value) {
    if (array_key_exists($property_name, $arr))
        //discarding protected and private member
        $obj->$property_name = $arr[$property_name];
}
```

Or just add iterate method on class A:

```
class A {
    public $a;
    public $b;

    function iterate($array) {
        foreach ($this as $property_name => $property_value) {
            if (array_key_exists($property_name, $array))
                $this->$propety_name = $array[$property_name];
        }
    }
    function f1 () {
        // Code
    }
}
```

and use the iterate() method.

Comment: The last code will affecting private and protected member in contrast the previous code. So choose according to your needs.